# Single word: Happiness caused by ones own misfortune

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word/loanword that means:

> "**happiness** caused by the **misfortune** of **oneself**"

I have put together all combinations that follow this pattern:

**(sadness|happiness)** caused by the **(misfortune|fortune)** of **(another|oneself)**

[image: row1:pity = (sadness) caused by the (misfortune) of (another), row2: schadenfreude = (happiness) caused by the (misfortune) of (another), row3: gluckschmerz = (sadness) caused by the (fortune) of (another), row4: mudita = (happiness) caused by the (fortune) of (another) row5: self-pity = (sadness) caused by the (misfortune) of (oneself) row6: ???? = (happiness) caused by the (misfortune) of (oneself) row7: ???? = (sadness) caused by the (fortune) of (oneself) row8: ???? = (happiness) caused by the (fortune) of (oneself)]

The closest I could get for **row 6** was "masochism", but:

1. "masochism" isn't precisely an emotion.
2. "masochism" implies voluntary infliction of pain on oneself, whereas misfortune (a.k.a. "bad luck") implies involuntary circumstance.

I guess one could label **row 6** self-schadenfreude...

As a bonus if anyone has any ideas for **row 7** and **row 8** they would also be appreciated!

Comment: I think you would be hard-pressed to find real-world scenarios for 6 and 7.

Comment: A real-life example might help you. Suppose a person applies for a job, is interviewed and is then told "Sorry, the job went to someone else." In his or her heart, the person could be relieved/happy/glad they didn't get the job, because it was not that appealing to them. By the same token, the same person could have gotten the job, but was sad with their good fortune because their life will get much more complicated, and they'll have very little free time. Leon Festinger's concept of cognitive dissonance can be applicable in either scenario.

Comment: [_satisfaction_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/satisfaction) might work in #8

Comment: @rhetorician Not getting the job is not a misfortune if he didn't really want it. Getting the job is not good fortune if it makes him sad.

Comment: For 6, I hear *low self-esteem*. For 7, there's a Yiddish saying (cue the gallows humor):  *Pity, the bride's too pretty* that means finding fault where you'd expect to be delighted (for bride, groom, and your own visual awe). Snatching defeat from the jaws of victory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two neologisms derived from *schadenfreude* for the happiness/joy from (caused by) one's own misfortune:

- **autoschadenfreude**
- **selbstschadenfreude**

They are used or discussed in various online sources and books in Google Books. There are some sources claiming the coinage of these words also.

> The American author AJ Jacobs coined a term for it: **autoschadenfreude** – the joy we take in our own misfortune.
> <sub>*[God Bless the NHS](https://books.google.es/books?id=JZ-sJ2C82zgC&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=autoschadenfreude&source=bl&ots=Nf4M8j3j2h&sig=ACfU3U1hVnemMedHyF-gPk-WWFvzfyqnNg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_kvu168H4AhUZ_4UKHWLSCEsQ6AF6BAgLEAM#v=onepage&q=autoschadenfreude&f=false)* - By Roger Taylor</sub>

> Noun. A malicious satisfaction in the misfortunes of yourself. 
> *I'm just going to stay in tonight and sulk: I'm really feeling the autoschadenfreude.* 
> <sub>*[Urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=autoschadenfreude)* entry for *autoschadenfreude*</sub>

> In the ongoing effort to enrich the Blogospherical vocabulary, I offer **Selbst Schadenfreude**, which I will translate as meaning "the malicious pleasure taken in one's own difficulties or downfall."
> <sub>[waldenswimmer.blogspot.com](http://waldenswimmer.blogspot.com/2009/11/origins-of-selbst-schadenfreude.html) (2009)</sub>

> The Ik have taken *Schadenfreude* (German for "joy from someone else's misfortune") and improved on it, turning it into, to coin a term, ***Selbstschadenfreude*** (joy from one's own misfortune).
> <sub>*[The Five Stages of Collapse: Survivors' Toolkit](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ut_0AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&dq=Selbstschadenfreude&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjflbXk58H4AhXW3oUKHQ76D0sQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=Selbstschadenfreude&f=false)* - By Dmitry Orlov (2013)</sub>

---

As a common expression, there is **wallow in self-pity/despair/defeat** that can be considered depending on the context.

> **wallow in self-pity/despair/defeat etc**
>
> to seem to enjoy being sad etc, especially because you get sympathy from other people – used to show disapproval 
> *He’d been feeling sorry for himself, wallowing in self-pity*.
> <sub>*[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/wallow-in-self-pity-despair-defeat-etc)*</sub>

---

Bonus attempt:

7. Sadness caused by the fortune of self:

I believe the phrase **tears of joy** comes close as a common expression. There is also **bittersweet** for the mixture of sadness and happiness. However, I'm tempted to coin **autoglückschmerz**.

8. Happiness caused by the fortune of self:

Simply **happiness** can be enough. Other words like **joy, delight** can be used depending on the context. If it is happiness from a life well-lived, happiness that spans across lifetime, there is the term **eudaimonia**. It is like a combination of well-being, happiness and flourishing; and the concept comes from Aristotle's Nicomachean Ethics. But again, one could coin **automudita** also.

Comment: I like wallow.  I was going to propose wallowing.  I think that is exactly it.